# change upload filename php

Tags: php, upload

I have a problem with changing the upload filename. I want de filename to be 1.pat for the first upload 2.pat for second et cetera. How can i do that? ('plaatje' means image in dutch)

```
<?php
function patuploader()
{ 
echo '
    <div id="uploadForm">
    <form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="plaatje">Plaatje:</label>
            <input type="file" name="plaatje" id="plaatje" /><br />
        <label for="submit"></label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Verstuur bestand!"       /><br />
</form>
</div>
 ';


 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_FILES['plaatje']) && $_FILES['plaatje']           ['type']=="application/octet-stream"){

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['plaatje']['tmp_name'], './upload/'.time().''.$_FILES['plaatje']['name']);

}elseif(isset($_FILES['plaatje']) && $_FILES['plaatje']['type']!="application/octet-stream"){

    echo '<span id="warning">it's not possible to upload this file. you can only upload .pat files.</span>';

}

# Lees de inhoud van de map uit
$bestandenRij = scandir('./upload');
$bestandenRij = array_reverse($bestandenRij);

foreach($bestandenRij as $bestand){
    # Toon alle bestanden anders dan . (localdir) en .. (magic escalator)
    if($bestand != '.' && $bestand != '..'){
        echo "\t<img src=\"./upload/".$bestand."\" width=\"20\"/><br />\r\n";
    }
 }
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: I hope you did see Stackoverflow's highlighting. You can start from that error.

Comment: First, find the highest number in the list of `.pat` files. Then add one and save the file to that number.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation of [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)